# Drupal7, dexp_page_elements module is missing

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I migrate a drupal site from old hosting to new, i do a copy of DB and folder, then i put on new hosting and site work fine, but show me this error

```
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: dexp_page_elements. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

i read many post, but all say me put back the module is missing but i dont have the files.

How i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i look on de DB inside the system table the route of module. Because u can find the folder module inside two routes /module /sites/all/modules/

then i look the .module file, and in my case the file extension was .modul, i chnage the extension to .modul**e** and its work for me